# Don't break if class instance is passed as initialization argument

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to add flexibility to a `python` class, so that it notices when one of the init arguments is already an instance of that class. Skip "Initial situation" if you don't mind, how I got here.

### Initial situation

I have this class:

```
class Pet:    
    def __init__(self, animal):
        self._animal = animal

    @property
    def present(self):
        return "This pet is a " + self._animal

    ...
```

and there are many functions which accept an instance of this class as an argument (`def f(pet, ...)`). Everything worked as expected.

I then wanted to add some flexibility to the usage of these functions: if the caller passes a `Pet` instance, everything keeps on working as before. In all other cases, a `Pet` instance is created. One way to achieve that, is like this:

```
def f(pet_or_animal, ...):
    if isinstance(pet_or_animal, Pet):  #Pet instance was passed
        pet = pet_or_animal
    else:                               #animal string was passed
        pet = Pet(pet_or_animal)
    ...
```

This also works as expected, but these lines are repeated in every function. Not DRY, not good.

### Goal

So, I'd like to extract the `if`/`else` from each of the functions, and integrate it into the Pet class itself. I tried changing its `__init__` method to

```
class PetA:            #I've changed the name to facilitate discussion here.
    def __init__(self, pet_or_animal):
        if isinstance(pet_or_animal, PetA):
            self = pet_or_animal
        else:
            self._animal = pet_or_animal

    ...
```

and start each function with

```
def f(pet_or_animal, ...):
    pet = PetA(pet_or_animal)
    ...
```

However, that is not working. If a Pet instance is passed, everything is good, but if a string is called, a Pet instance is not correctly created.

### Current (ugly) solution

What *is* working, is to add a class method to the class, like so:

```
class PetB:            #I've changed the name to facilitate discussion here.
    @classmethod
    def init(cls, pet_or_animal):
        if isinstance(pet_or_animal, PetB):
            return pet_or_animal
        else:
            return cls(pet_or_animal)

    def __init__(self, animal):
        self._animal = animal

    ...
```

and also change the functions to

```
def f(pet_or_animal, ...):
    pet = PetB.init(pet_or_animal)  #ugly
    ...
```

### Questions

- Does anyone know, how to change class `PetA` so, that it has the intended behavior? To be sure, here is the quick test:

```
pb1 = PetB.init('dog')
pb2 = PetB.init(pb1)      #correctly initialized; points to same instance as pb1 (as desired)
pa1 = PetA('cat')
pa2 = PetA(pa1)           #incorrectly initialized; pa1 != pa2
```

- More generally, is this the right way to go about adding this flexibility? Another option I considered was writing a separate function to just do the checking, but this too is rather ugly and yet another thing to keep track of. I'd rather keep everything neat and wrapped in the class itself.
- And one final remark: I realize that some people might find the added class method (`petB`) a more elegant solution. The reason I prefer to add to the `__init__` method (`petA`) is that, in my real-world use, I already allow for many different types of initialization arguments. So, there is already a list of `if`/`elif`/`elif`/... statements that check, just which of the possibilities is used by the creator. I'd like to extend that by one more case, namely, if an initialized instance is passed.

Many thanks

Comment: Flexibility in this case is not a virtue. Just accept a `Pet` instance, and let the *caller* worry about creating such an instance if they don't already have one.

Comment: Thanks @chepner that's a helpful way to think about it

Answer (score 1):

I believe your current "ugly" solution is actually the correct approach.

This pushes the flexibility up as far as possible, since it is messy.  Even though python allows for arbitrary types and values to float around, your users and yourself will thank you for keeping that constrained to the outermost levels.

I would think of it as (don't need to implement it this way)

```
   class Pet:
       @classmethod
       def from_animal(cls, ...):
          ...

       @classmethod
       def from_pet(cls, ...):
          ...

       @classmethod
       def auto(cls, ...):
           if is_pet(...):
               return cls.from_pet(...)

       def __init__(cls, internal_rep):
           ...
```

etc.

It is a code smell if you don't know whether your function is taking an object or an initializer.  See if you can do processing as up-front as possible with user input and standardize everything beyond there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I had read about this coding style (the `.from_...` class methods) but I had stuck to my flexible approach nonetheless. I have now refactored the code as per your suggestion and it did indeed make it quite a bit more transparent and manageable I think. As this code is 'just for me' I can still make changes to the signatures without breaking things.

Comment: Great!  Glad it helped a little, always satisfying when things fall into place

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function instead to get the same behaviour you want:

```
def make_pet_if_required(pet_or_animal):
        if isinstance(pet_or_animal, PetA):
            return pet_or_animal
        else:
            return Pet(pet_or_animal)
```

And then:

```
def f(pet_or_animal, ...):
    pet = make_pet_if_required(pet_or_animal)
    ...
```

For more "beauty" you can try turning that function call into a decorator.